# Linear transforms question

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $T_s$ be the counter-clockwise rotation about the positive y-axis through an angle $\varphi$.

Write the standard matrix of as $T_s$.

I'm not entirely comfortable when questions present themselves geometrically and would like any suggestions to start. I know this $T_s$ is mapping $R^3$ to itself since it's rotation of the xz plane. I'm just not sure how to write that in terms of vectors. Any guidance would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We want to know where $T_s$ sends the the three standard basis vectors $e_1,e_2$ and $e_3$. Since $T_s$ is a rotation about the $y$-axis, it fixes $e_2$ i.e. $T_se_2=e_2$. Now we restrict our attention to the $xz$-plane. Since $T_s$ is a rotation by $\varphi$ in the $xz$-plane, we have that $T_se_1=\cos(\varphi) e_1+\sin(\varphi)e_3$ and $T_se_3=-\sin(\varphi)e_1+\cos(\varphi)e_3$. Thus
$$T_s=\begin{pmatrix}
\cos \varphi & 0 & -\sin\varphi\\
0 & 1 & 0\\
\sin\varphi & 0 & \cos\varphi
\end{pmatrix}$$